# Python twisted putChild not forwarding expectedly

Tags: python-3.x, twisted, twisted.web

Code here.

```
from twisted.web.static import File
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.internet import ssl, reactor
from twisted.python.modules import getModule
import secure_aes
import urllib.parse
import cgi
import json
import os
import hashlib
import coserver
import base64
import sim

if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'images')):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'images'))


with open ('form.html','r') as f:
    fillout_form = f.read()
with open ('image.html','r') as f:
    image_output = f.read()


port = 80#int(os.environ.get('PORT', 17995))
class FormPage(Resource):
    #isLeaf = True
    def getChild(self, name, request):
        print('GC')
        if name == '':
            return self
        return Resource.getChild(self, name, request)


    def render_GET(self, request):
        print(request)
        #do stuff and return stuff

root = FormPage()
root.putChild('rcs', File("./images"))
#factory = Site(FormPage())
factory = Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(port, factory)
reactor.run()
```

As you can see, I did `root.putChild` towards the end of things, expecting that when I got to `http://site/rcs` I get given a directory listing of the contents of `./images` but of course that doesn't happen. What am I missing? I've tried many things suggested from [here](http://mtrpcic.net/blog/twisted-static-content-with-dynamic-pages/). Also [this one](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/web/howto/web-in-60/static-dispatch.html) doesn't work because that's just serving static files anyways. It goes to getChild all the time regardless of whether if have specified putChild or not.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  I deleted a bunch of extraneous stuff but left the core intact - and it serves a directory listing for me.

Comment: What version of Twisted, Python, what OS, etc.

Comment: Python 3.5, Windows 10. No venv.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Python 3, a bare string literal like `"rcs"` is a unicode string (which Python 3 calls "str" but which I will call "unicode" to avoid ambiguity).

However, `twisted.web.resource.Resource.putChild` requires a byte string as its first argument.  It misbehaves rather poorly when given unicode, instead.  Make your path segments into byte strings (eg `b"rcs"`) and the server will behave better on Python 3.